# CodeIgniter - Sending array from model to controller to page

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to pass the array to the view page and put the items in a listbox/dropdown. Where am I going wrong in this code?

Model

```
public function get_suppliers(){
        $type = "SUPPLIER";
        $this->db->where('usertype', $type);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $results = array(
                'userid' => $row->userid,
                'firstname' => $row->firstname,
                'lastname' => $row->lastname,
                'company' => $row->company
            );

        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Controller

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$data['supplier']= $this->user_model->get_suppliers();
$this->load->view('include/header.php');
$this->load->view('addvehicle_view', $data);
$this->load->view('include/footer.php');
```

View

```
<?php
  if(isset($supplier)){
      foreach ($supplier as $info){
      echo'<option value="' . $info->userid . '">' . $info->company . ' - ' . $info->lastname . ', ' . $info->firstname . '</option>';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `get_suppliers()`:

```
$results = array(); // just in case there is no record

foreach (...) {
    $results[] = array( // you forgot the "[]"
        ...
    );
}
```

Another issue: your model (once fixed) returns an array of arrays, whereas your view expects an array of objects.

Straight to the point, here's your new sexy model method:

```
public function get_suppliers() {
    return $this->db
        ->where('usertype', 'SUPPLIER')
        ->get('users')
        ->result();
}
```

Comment: I dump the array using var_dump in the view page and below is what I got but it is not pulling correctly in the foreach loop. Do you see and issue with the for each loop in the View? array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["userid"]=> string(1) "3" ["firstname"]=> string(13) "SupplierFirst" ["lastname"]=> string(12) "SupplierLast" ["company"]=> string(9) "Supply Co" } }

Comment: Looks like you didn't read my answer. I just edited it to add a ready-to-use code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_suppliers(){
    $type = "SUPPLIER";
    $this->db->where('usertype', $type);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $results = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $results[] = array(
                'userid' => $row->userid,
                'firstname' => $row->firstname,
                'lastname' => $row->lastname,
                'company' => $row->company
        );

    }
    return $results;
}
```